Migrating from Elastic Search 6.8 to 8+ along with High level client Upgrade (NEST)
Currently we are using Elastic search 6.8 for all our Dotnet projects,For High level client we are using Nest 6.5 .We are thinking to upgrade to ES 8+ for obvious reasons as the current version is EOL.Along with this upgrade we also need to upgrade our High level client to Elastic.Clinets.Elasticsearch 8+ since Nest is also deprecated and is EOL.These two are breaking changes and there is no proper documentation to follow for these upgrades.Documentation in elastic side is also not much user friendly and for High level client we don't have a proper documentation yet.Has anyone upgraded from lower version to 8+along with High level clinet upgrade ?if so please share your experience and strategy to be followed along with any documentation.

if at all possible, create a new separate 8.16 (latest) cluster and migrate over step by step (even host/node by host). Don't try to do this on existing environment.
